# Technical reasons to not use HTTP authentication

Tags: http, authentication, post

I discovered that **HTTP supports a system of authentication** to restrict the readability of an information. Why do most common websites **use their own system**, with a session, and many stuff to manage this kind of information rather than HTTP authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do most common websites use their own system, with a session, and many stuff to manage this kind of information rather than HTTP authentication?

If anything, it's because http basic auth presents an ugly blocking modal window when asking for credentials, which, among other things, makes it impossible to customize login parameters ("remember me" / "this is a public computer" checkbox, for example. Or captcha).

Comment: But http is just a protocol no ? so it's free to the browser to implement it no ?

Comment: @Xjames56X: As a developer of a hugely popular site, I do not want to leave it up to browser vendors. I want my UX to be consistent across browsers.

Comment: Understood. But, it's bad that the protocol think about it but its really not used in real life...

Comment: @Xjames56X: oh, it's being used. Just not in apps for general public. :)